# Rendering Snackbar causes unit tests to fail

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-native-paper

I have a simple unit test I'm trying to setup with Jest and React Testing Library that clicks a button to make a `<Snackbar />` appear from [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/), the problem I'm having is that once the Snackbar is visible my tests end up timing out, I assume because of the `duration` prop that automatically dismisses the Snackbar component on a timeout.

```
const Component = props => {
  const [snackbarVisible, setSnackbarVisible] = useState(false)
  const onClick = (): void => {
    setSnackbarVisible(true)
    props.saveHandler()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button mode="contained" onPress={onClick}>
        Save
      </Button>
      <Snackbar
        visible={snackbarVisible}
        onDismiss={() => setSnackbarVisible(false)}
        duration={5000}
        action={{
          label: 'Dismiss',
          onPress: () => setSnackbarVisible(false)
        }}
      >
        Saved!
      </Snackbar>
    </>
  )
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
it('saves the cabinet', async () => {
  const saveHandler = jest.fn()

  jest.useFakeTimers()

  const {getByText} = render(<Component saveHandler={saveHandler} />)

  fireEvent.press(getByText('Save'))
  fireEvent.press(getByText('Dismiss'))

  // This was removed from the example for simplicity.
  expect(saveHandler).toBeCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Keeping it makes the tests timeout with the following error. Removing the `Snackbar` gives the tests an actual failure.

```
 FAIL  src/views/CabinetView/CabinetView.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Call retries were exceeded
```

I've tried using a number of variants of `useFakeTimers` but I can't seem to get it to work correctly in this instance.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't you be waiting for something somewhere? https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async

Comment: I've tried waiting for the element to appear after the initial press: `waitForElement(() => getByText('Dismiss'))` but it still times out the test for whatever reason. It doesn't seem to matter how long I set the `duration` prop to either, it can be `1` and the problem persists.

Comment: what I don't see in the test is the firing of save button press event

Comment: I added it to the example. It's not relevant to repro the problem though. It doesn't matter what the test does so long as the `Snackbar` is present on the page. It can even be defaulted to visible and it will still timeout. I'm guessing the component triggers a `setTimeout` under the hood when it's visible and that's whats causing the tests to timeout too.

Comment: check out the test for that component in react-native-paper code maybe you find something you are missing there https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/master/src/components/__tests__/Snackbar.test.js